# Green color of a <li> tag using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My book shows the difference between javascript and jquery but neither script works. Can I see both work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" src="myCss.css"></style>
    <script>

     (function(document){
          document.onload = function(){
              content.style.display = "block";
          }

          var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");          
          for(i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
              listItems[i].onclick = function{
                  listItems[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";    
              }                           
          }          
      })( document );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="content" class="contentClass">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" src="myCss.css"></style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $( "#content" ).show();
          $( "li" ).click(function(this){
              this.css( "backgroundColor","green" );
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="content" class="contentClass">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to do modicfiche on both but I have not solved. I found parentheses going badly, awkward posture of the script.

Comment: @captainsac - `backgroundColor` is the javascript that is used for the css attribute `background-color`.

Comment: @Jamiec you are right, but how could this work http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/57/?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - because jQuery is nice/helpful, and will accept the css name or the javascript name I assume.

Comment: Let me know if none of the answers worked or you still need help

Answer (score 4):

jQuery, try with:

```
$("li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "green");
});
```

Native js:

```
for(i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].onclick = function{
        this.style.backgroundColor = "green";  
    }                           
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the **javascript** version,

1. Put `()` after `function` or its a syntax error.
2. Use `this` instead of `listItems[i].style` because then you have to correctly make a closure to pass in the `i` and that is the more complicated route. `this` in the click handler will refer to the clicked `li` itself

```js
(function(document){
          document.onload = function(){
              content.style.display = "block";
          }

          var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");          
          for(i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
              listItems[i].onclick = function(){
                  this.style.backgroundColor = "green";    
              }                           
          }          
      })( document );
```

```html
<ul id="content" class="contentClass">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
```

For the **jQuery** version,

1. You do not need to pass `this` in to the click handler
2. Use `$(this)` instead of `this` because you are calling a jQuery function `css()` and need the jQuery object( *$(this)* )

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $( "#content" ).show();
          $( "li" ).click(function(){
              $(this).css( "background-color","green" );
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="content" class="contentClass">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I dont know, I upvoted as this does exactly what the OP asked for - a comparison of the 2 versions.

Comment: What about $(this).addClass("green-background");

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Comment: @Jamiec op's code creates console error. I just corrected that code.

Comment: I will quote it, you seem to have trouble understanding *My book shows the difference between javascript and jquery but neither script works. Can I see both work*

Comment: @Jamiec atleast this provide a jquery solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "green");
```

Comment: You've asked another question as an answer. Did you mean to write a comment? Also, the OP asked for the 2 versions (vanilla js and jQuery), you've just put a single line of jQuery, without any context of where it should go or how to use it. This is a bad answer.

Comment: agreed but what you are saying about valnilla?